# Python import works, but using the imported item fails. Using Django, but this seems like a newbie Python issue

Tags: python, django, import

I am running through the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial02/).

I have this file

```
R:\jeffy\programming\sandbox\python\django_files\tutorial\django_test\...
...django_test\article\views.py
```

Contents:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.

def hello(request):
    name = "Mike"
    html = "<html><body>Hi %s, this seems to have worked</body></html>" % name
    return  HttpResponse(html)
```

And this file:

```
R:\jeffy\programming\sandbox\python\django_files\tutorial\django_test\...
...django_test\urls.py
```

Contents:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from article.views import hello

urlpatterns = patterns('',
#    url(r'^hello/', include(article.views.hello)),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

I start the Django server

```
python manage.py runserver
```

and go to

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

And it works:

[image: root success]

As does this

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin
```

[image]

But when I uncomment the "hello" line, it fails:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from article.views import hello

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^hello/', include(article.views.hello)), # <--Problem line
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

[image]

The error says

```
R:\\jeffy\\programming\\sandbox\\python\\django_files\\tutorial\\django_test
```

is in the PYTHONPATH, and the "article" folder is *in that directory*.

Also, why does the `import article` line not cause an error, but calling the `hello` function does fail.

---

Please help me. What am I missing?

---

***UPDATE***

No import at all fails the same way (`NameError at / name 'article' is not defined`):

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^hello/', include(article.views.hello)),   # <-- Problem line
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Using `import article` only, causes this error: `AttributeError at / 'module' object has no attribute 'views'`

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
import article

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^hello/', include(article.views.hello)),   # <-- Problem line
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Eliminating the import and putting the call in strings (as suggested), results in an `ImportError at / No module named 'article.views.hello'; 'article.views' is not a package`:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^hello/', include(article.views.hello)),   # <-- Problem line
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

And, finally, importing the `hello` function directly:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from article.views import hello

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^hello/', include(hello)),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

With this, calling `http://127.0.0.1:8000` fails but *in an expected way*:

[image]

But then, `http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello` fails with this:

[image]

Comment: Did you add 'article' to `INSTALLED_APPS` in your Django settings?

Comment: @erewok Yes. `'article'` is one of the items in `INSTALLED_APPS`, in `R:\jeffy\programming\sandbox\python\django_files\tutorial\django_test\django_test\settings.py`

Comment: Try using only `hello` instead of `article.views.hello`. It's because the way you imported it I think. Edit: See erewoks answer :)

Comment: just do `import article` instead of `from article.views import hello`. Or even better just git rid of the import and put `article.views.hello` in strings => `'article.views.hello'`

Comment: @karthikr I tried what you suggested. Please see the update in my question-post.

Comment: You're still trying to call the `include` function on a function. I commented on this below. Don't use `include.`

Comment: Right. I misunderstood. Your answer's point number two worked perfectly.

Comment: @karthikr  Importing nothing, and using `url(r'^hello/', 'article.views.hello')` also works. Thank you for the alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few things that are wrong here.

1) You are importing something you are not using:

```
from article.views import hello

    ...

    url(r'^hello/', include(article.views.hello)),
```

You import `hello` and then call it from the module `article`, but `article` has not been imported and so will be undefined. You can either import `article` or you can call `hello` directly.

2) `include` is not necessary here.

We normally use `include` for including other `urls.py` schemas. `hello` is a function. The way that url-routing works in Django is that you define a route and pass it a function, like so:

```
from article.views import hello

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^hello/', hello),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: You would have to get rid of the strings around hello for it to work.

Comment: That's my most-common Django typo.

Comment: @erewok I tried your suggestions. Please see the update in my question-post.

Comment: I saw "include" and my mind changed it to "import". Your code under number two works exactly. It also works with `from article import views` ... `url(r'^hello/', views.hello)`. But `import article` ... `url(r'^hello/', article.views.hello)` fails with `AttributeError at /hello/ \n 'module' object has no attribute 'views'`. If you happen to know why, I'd like to understand this. Either way, you got my up-vote and acceptance! Thanks a lot.

Comment: That has to do with packaging and will take too long to explain here. Short version, you can access elements of a module in tht way if you define them (through imports) in the module's `__init__.py`